# Receiving data on server side using BufferedInputStream

Tags: java

I have some troubles with receiving data on server side. Here goes the code:

on client part i have :

```
 public void sendMessage(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    byte[] lenghtInBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(bytes.length).array();
    out.write(lenghtInBytes,0,4);
    out.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    out.flush();
}
```

on server part i have function:

```
 public byte[] receiveMessage() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    byte[] lenghtInBytes = new byte[4];
    in.read(lenghtInBytes,0,4);
    int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenghtInBytes).getInt();
    serverLogger.debug(length);
    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    in.read(data,0, length);
    serverLogger.debug(new String(data));
    return data;
}
```

in server main :

```
 out = new BufferedOutputStream(sslClientSocket.getOutputStream());
 out.flush();
 in = new BufferedInputStream(sslClientSocket.getInputStream());
 System.out.println(new String(receiveString()));
 System.out.println(new String(receiveString()));
```

in client main :

```
 sendMessage(firstData.getBytes());
 sendMessage(secondData.getBytes());
```

as a result on server side i receive only firstdata correctly, and secondData is empty(is 0). Why is this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that on the server side was used jre6, while client application  was running on jre7.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedInputStream.read(byte[] b,int off, int len) reads only available bytes. To read all bytes, you have to wrap in.read() in a loop.

Comment: "...As an additional convenience, it attempts to read as many bytes as possible by repeatedly invoking the read method of the underlying stream...." form here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html